# How to change form_set_error() message in captcha module

Tags: captcha

I need to reset the default error message in the captcha module when you enter the wrong answer.

captcha.module line 616

```
form_set_error('captcha_response', t('The answer you entered for the CAPTCHA was not correct.'));
```

I'm not quite sure where this needs to be done. Preprocess function?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830379/drupal-customizing-validation-error-messages

Answer (score 2):

Check out [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. It allows you to override any translatable string (anything that uses `t()`) and is very convenient for overriding some text that is shipped with other modules.

If you want to do it without installing new modules - uncomment and edit this in the `settings.php` file (line ~458):

```
# $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
#   'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
#   '@count min' => '@count minutes',
# );
```

Comment: This would work, but we cannot currently add any more modules. It must be done in code.

Comment: Answer updated.